# How do I create an AJAX form with Add and Remove buttons for multi-value form element without submission button?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I would like to create a custom form with a textfield in which I input some data and it gets saved in the variable table.

The form should only contain the *Add*, *Remove*, and *Add more* button to add additional textfields.

When the textfield is empty, there should be an *Add* button; when the textfield is not empty, there should be a *Remove* button.
Clicking on the *Add more* button should create an empty textfield with an *Add* button.

All this need to happen without page reload.

I was able to add the *Add*, *Remove*, *Add more*, and *Submit* buttons. 
I looked into the available resources and example modules, but I can't find helpful resources.

Can anyone help me to modify the code so that the *Submit* button can be removed?

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['admin/mymodule'] = array(
        'title' => t('Example form'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('mymodule_ajax_example_add_more'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

    return $items;
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more($form, &$form_state) {
  $mymodule_ajax_events = variable_get('mymodule_ajax_example_content', array());
  $mymodule_ajax_events_count = count($mymodule_ajax_events);
  if ($mymodule_ajax_events_count == 0) {
    $mymodule_ajax_events_count = 1;
  }

  $form = array();
  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $form['mymodule_ajax_events'] = [
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#weight' => 80,
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    // Set up the wrapper so that AJAX will be able to replace the fieldset.
    '#prefix' => '<div id="js-ajax-elements-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];
  $form_state['field_deltas'] = isset($form_state['field_deltas']) ? $form_state['field_deltas'] : range(0, $mymodule_ajax_events_count-1);

  $field_count = $form_state['field_deltas'];
  foreach ($field_count as $delta) {
    $form['mymodule_ajax_events'][$delta] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['container-inline'],
      ],
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['mymodule_ajax_events'][$delta]['event_url'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Event URL' . ($delta + 1)),
      '#size' => 40,
      '#default_value' => (isset($mymodule_ajax_events[$delta])) ? $mymodule_ajax_events[$delta] : '',
    ];

    $form['mymodule_ajax_events'][$delta]['remove_event_url'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Remove'),
      '#submit' => ['mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_remove'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_remove_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'js-ajax-elements-wrapper',
      ],
      '#weight' => 50,
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['button-small'],
      ],
      '#name' => 'remove_event_url_' . $delta,
    );
  }

  $form['mymodule_ajax_events']['add_event_url'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add one more'),
    '#submit' => ['mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_add_one'],
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_add_one_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'js-ajax-elements-wrapper',
    ],
    '#weight' => 1,
  );
    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#weight' => 100,
  );

  return $form;
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_remove($form, &$form_state) {
  $delta_remove = $form_state['triggering_element']['#parents'][1];
  $k = array_search($delta_remove, $form_state['field_deltas']);
  unset($form_state['field_deltas'][$k]);

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  drupal_get_messages();
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_remove_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['mymodule_ajax_events'];
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_add_one($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['field_deltas'][] = count($form_state['field_deltas']) > 0 ? max($form_state['field_deltas']) + 1 : 0;
  //mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_validate();
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  // drupal_get_messages();
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_add_one_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['mymodule_ajax_events'];
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_validate($form, $form_state) {
    dpm($form_state);
  foreach ($form_state['values']['mymodule_ajax_events'] as $key => $item) {
      //dpm($item);
      dpm($item['event_url']);
   if (!empty($item['event_url'])) {
      if (!preg_match('/https:\/\/example.com.*/i', $item['event_url'])) {
        form_set_error("mymodule_ajax_events][$key][event_url", 'Enter a valid Event URL.' . ($key + 1));
        //
      }else{
       drupal_set_message('URL ' . ($key + 1) . ' Created' );
   }
  }
 }
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $events_content = array();
  $events_count = 0;
  foreach ($form_state['values']['mymodule_ajax_events'] as $key => $item) {
    if (!empty($item['event_url'])) {
      $events_content[] = $item['event_url'];
      $events_count++;
   }
 }
  variable_set('mymodule_ajax_example_content', $events_content);
  variable_set('mymodule_ajax_example_count', $events_count);
}
```

Comment: Hey student, welcome to the club!  Saw you tagging some questions with version tags lately. Please note: `Version tags should be used for questions that apply to a version only, not to merely say what version a site is using.` as this otherwise would cause lots of duplicate questions where just the version tag differs. There also already was lots of discussion on Meta about version tag usage in the past. Maybe have a glimpse at them and chime in if you disagree. Keep up the work, see you 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit the submit button altogether, you need to move the logic of the validate and submit to the ajax callbacks.

First, remove the submit button:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
  '#weight' => 100,
];
```

Now you can take the logic from `mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_validate` and from `mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_submit` to the various ajax callbacks.

Each time the user interacts with the ajax buttons, you must validate the data and if all goes well, rewrite the variable to the database, because as far as we concern, this was the last interaction the user has with this form.